# Set django.contrib.auth.views.login as csrf_exempt

Tags: iphone, python, django, ios, django-csrf

I'm developing a just-for-learn iOS app who interacts with my Django application.

I'm at login part: my client fails to login into Django app due to csrf protection.

For the others views I just would add `csrf_exempt` decorator for disable it, but for built-in `django.contrib.auth.views.login` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In modern Django (last tested on 1.11), one way to disable the CSRF check is to subclass the `LoginView` and override its `dispatch` method, which is explicitly decorated with `csrf_protect` ([as seen here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/7724879b524711d61b7491a4a9c104d9cff2e1e3/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L56)).

The resulting CBV is along the lines of:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


class DangerousLoginView(LoginView):
    '''A LoginView with no CSRF protection.'''

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.redirect_authenticated_user and self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            redirect_to = self.get_success_url()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
        return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

[See the entire `urls.py` file here.](https://gist.github.com/mvasilkov/c4dcf5300b12886ffb61e64b745cb1b1)

The idea is to replicate the exact same method, while replacing `csrf_protect` with `csrf_exempt`. There might be a cleaner way to do this, for example, using [undecorated](https://github.com/mapleoin/undecorated).

Comment: Returns me error `"TemplateSyntaxError at / Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for ''django.contrib.auth.views.login'' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found."` on this HTML line: `<a href="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}">login</a>`

Comment: @Fred Collins: use `{% url login %}` instead.

Comment: Now It works the template but I still get the error for the csrf protection. Weird.

Comment: It does not work for me either. Why is it marked as an answer?

Comment: @HassanBaig I've updated the answer. In Django 1.11, the following code works for me: https://gist.github.com/mvasilkov/c4dcf5300b12886ffb61e64b745cb1b1

Comment: The updated answer worked for me once I changed "self.request" to "request" to use the local version

Answer (score 0):

In your template: users/login.html where you have the POST line you need to amend to include:

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

ie:

```
<form action="{{ app_path }}" method="post" id="login-form">{% csrf_token %}
```